# X Server closing without errors

Tags: linux, drivers, centos-7, display-driver, nvidia-quadro

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on my centos 7.6 install. I've managed to install them from Nvidia's website with a successful install (according to the .sh installer). However, every time I try and and start X it crashes. Here's the log file: https://pastebin.com/AVRRQgc4 . I can't see any error messages so I'm grasping at straws for answers. Can anyone see anything that I missed?

Comment: what about you delete xorg.conf file?

Comment: I get the same crash pretty much, nothing new in the Xorg.0.log

Comment: On which way do you call X? By start gdb or similar or simply startx?

Comment: just startx, i tailed /var/log/messages and the following turns up when i try to startx. https://pastebin.com/bx5gZ4Kk

Comment: I find out this discussions seems related to you issue: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=143753